# scope().$apply(); isn't working in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer, sharepoint

My JS:

```
function redirect(aPath) {
    var app = $('#divMain').injector();
    if (aPath == app.get('$location').path()) {
        app.get('$state').reload();
    }
    else {
        app.get('$location').path(aPath);
    }
    $('#divMain').scope().$apply();
}
```

These cases works fine in Chrome, but in IE when I click on same page nav link i.e the "if" condition the scope().$apply() doesn't fire. Am I missing something?

Same scenario is there in Tablet(iPad) also even in Chrome.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you working with?

Comment: @Thriggle **Sharepoint 2010**

Comment: In that case, SharePoint is probably forcing Internet Explorer into compatibility mode, which emulates IE8. Test your JavaScript against IE8 and use polyfills as needed. Note that you need to explicitly use jQuery 1.12 for IE8 support; the latest version of jQuery only works with IE9+.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
angular.element($('#divMain')).scope().$apply();
```

Comment: It's still the same.